# Replace text before last slash, between quotes and on certain line

Tags: awk, sed

If I had a text file, with multiple lines of:

```
source = "/directory/something/module1"
sometext sometext
source = "/directory/something/module2"
sometext sometext
source = "/directory/something/module3"
```

So for every line that has `source = "/some directory/some module"`

I want to replace the data before the last forward slash. So I'll end with something like:

```
source = "./module/module1"
sometext sometext
source = "./module/module2"
sometext sometext
source = "./module/module3"
```

The module names need to be preserved, and their containing directory replaced.

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code which is highly encouraged on SO.

Comment: `sed -e '/source/s@".*/@"./module/@' file`

Comment: Thanks @kvantour, that worked, even though I don't understand why 

Comment: philthy - @karakfas suggestion would work for the sample input posted but not for other input. try replacing `sometext` on any line with `my "problem" source is that N/0 is invalid` for example. A script that produces the expected output for a given sample input is the starting point to identifying a solution, not the end point and it's always trivial to match the text you want but much harder to not match the text you don't want.

Comment: It's important to understand a potential solution before deciding that it works and it's important to put effort into creating sample input/output that'll test more than just your sunny day cases, especially cover the cases that you can imagine might result in a match that you do NOT want to match but look similar to the ones you do.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '/^source.*module[0-9]+$/{sub(/\/.*\//,"./module/")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                         ##Starting awk program from here.
/^source.*module[0-9]+$/{     ##Checking condition if line starts from source and ends with module digits then do following.
  sub(/\/.*\//,"./module/")   ##Substituting from slash to last occurrence of s;ash with ./module/ here.
}
1                             ##1 will print line.
' Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `sed` with 2 captured groups:

```sh
sed -E 's~(source *= *").*(/[^/]+")~\1./module\2~' file

source = "./module/module1"
sometext sometext
source = "./module/module2"
sometext sometext
source = "./module/module3"
```

To save changes inline to same file, use:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's~(source *= *").*(/[^/]+")~\1./module\2~' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for this:

```
awk -F\/ '$(NF) ~ /module/ { $0="source = \"./module/"$(NF) }1' file
```

Set the field delimiter to / and then search for any entries where the last field contains module. For these entries, change $0 (the line) to the reformatted line, incorporating the last field. Print all lines with short hand 1.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this simple `awk` can help using `gsub()` function:

```
awk '/"\/directory\/something\/module1"/ gsub(/\/directory\/something/,"./module")1' file
```